# How to show Form region show on top of reading pane outlook vsto

Tags: outlook, vsto

I am developing VSTO Addin and using Form region . Wanted to show Form region always at top of reading pane. By default it is showing only at bottom .

Any one having any idea ? which property or method I can use to show at top .

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: I do not think you can move on top, but you can implement custom task panel which allow user to set postion TOP, LEFT, RIGHT and BUTTOM